# Audio from MPMoviePlayerController continues playing after segue to next view controller

Tags: swift, segue, mpmovieplayercontroller

After adding a video file, the audio from the video preview continues even after a segue to the next VC is pressed.

Is there any way to stop the audio from playing after the segue is pressed?

```
var objMoviePlayerController: MPMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController()
var urlVideo: NSURL = NSURL()

@IBOutlet weak var videoprofileView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var addvideoBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    var theHeight = view.frame.size.height

    videoprofileView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, theWidth, theWidth)
    addvideoBtn.center = CGPointMake(theWidth/2, self.videoprofileView.frame.maxY+50)
}

@IBAction func addvideoBtn_click(sender: AnyObject) {
    var ipcVideo = UIImagePickerController()
    ipcVideo.delegate = self
    ipcVideo.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    ipcVideo.allowsEditing = true
    ipcVideo.videoMaximumDuration = 15

    var kUTTypeMovieAnyObject : AnyObject = kUTTypeMovie as AnyObject
    ipcVideo.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovieAnyObject]
    self.presentViewController(ipcVideo, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    urlVideo = (info as NSDictionary).objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL) as! NSURL
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    objMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: urlVideo)
    objMoviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
    objMoviePlayerController.view.frame = self.videoprofileView.bounds
    objMoviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill
    objMoviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
    objMoviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = true

    videoprofileView.addSubview(objMoviePlayerController.view)

    objMoviePlayerController.prepareToPlay()
    objMoviePlayerController.play()
}

@IBAction func next_click(sender: AnyObject) {
    let data:NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlVideo)!
    let file = PFFile(name:"video.mp4", data:data)
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
    currentUser["video"] = file

    currentUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock( {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("video saved")
        } else {
            println("couldn't save video")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell your video to `stop` before segueing to the next view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
    objMoviePlayerController.stop()
}
```

[**MPMediaPlayback Protocol Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MPMediaPlayback/stop)